# Argument of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Jumping in the deep end with Typescript and running into the following error:

**Error**

```
Argument of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
```

**Script.js**

```
let name;
const targetNode = document.querySelectorAll('[data="record"]');
const config = { attributes: true };

const callback = () => {
    const recordNameString = targetNode[1].textContent;
    const nameArray = recordNameString.split(' ');
    name = nameArray[0];

    chrome.storage.local.set({ name });

    console.log(name);
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Error kicks in here
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Why is this occuring and how can I resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
observer.observe(targetNode, config)
```

`targetNode` is of type `NodeListOf<Element>`, which is not the same as type `Node`: it's a list of `Element`s. The method `observe` expects a first argument of type `Node`.

The type `Element` extends type `Node`, though, so you can do this:

```
targetNode.forEach(node => observer.observe(node, config));
```

if you're wanting all of the elements in that list to be observed.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAdghgtiA3AKAMYHsoGdJhgJwHNwA5dAExAgF4Jz1UBXBKMAOgEdGR8BPAZRChUYdPgCCwYAAoA5AG1yMPNQBE%20EBnzlVAXVkBKFBmyQTAMwCWhGhADeEZWHyWARozAgsALgjPuEAC%20KGiYOBCoMFKuMKgA1rbSBjQAfPbIEJkRYZAaWuQk8CD8zpZQNrR4RKQUIPIAjLpsngAeYADCmJ6sKFnZptBF4vj4MLy2eWIFRSUu5WxYAA7AlmByEIa9WbAItjsgw6O88gAMuiF9qAAW%20OgIC6KjxGzADFEL4NIO%200FGyBlZExYdCgF7oQjSfZ-YL-IGQdCuLA8ABuPD2IAA7hAALIeZSWTAAeURKJ40ki0VicT%20yAA9LSIABREZiCBxSzxLAQMoQK48EDIKrEMBkShscxiRmxK6Q2qpCAIpH4VH4NiK0myygAGn6VkIBiMQA)